# Process performance counter is disabled, so the requested operation cannot be performed

Tags: vb.net

I don't see why this doesn't work.

I have gone into the registry and removed the registry key below and still no joy. The error arises at the For Each Loop. If anyone could help it would be appreciated.
 I am using .net framework 1.1
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\PerfProc\Performance\Disable performance counters

```
If System.IO.File.Exists(path) Then
    System.IO.File.Delete(path)
    ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = False
    ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(path)
    ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = True

    ExcelApp.Quit()
    MessageBox.Show("File Exported to: " & path)

    Dim proc As System.Diagnostics.Process
    For Each proc In System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("EXCEL")
        'Debug.Print(Now() & " - Killing process ID " & proc.Id)
        proc.Kill()
    Next



Else
    'saves the file
    ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = False
    ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(path)
    ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = True
    ExcelApp.Quit()

    Dim proc As System.Diagnostics.Process
    For Each proc In System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("EXCEL")
        'Debug.Print(Now() & " - Killing process ID " & proc.Id)
        proc.Kill()
```

Comment: I am able to run your code without any issues. What is the error you are getting. Also I have assumed Dim ExcelApp As New Excel.Application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might be a permission issue.

Take a look at [Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/netfxbcl/thread/482b5994-32a4-4c95-a73f-3c05ca2aaf93) and [Here](http://weblogs.asp.net/nunitaddin/archive/2004/11/21/267559.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed, this works on my managers PC. It is down to me not being on an admin account